# Python - replace not working on special character in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace `{`, `\xad`, `\xa`. However below code isn't replacing it. I am trying to figure why it is not removing it? I even tried escape character. Any advise? Thanks.

```
lista = ['ISBN{124123{A{112','ISBN{124312412412{D{2352342','AGEWE21\xad13\xadC\xad93872\xa0']
lista = [i for i in lista if not i.replace("\{", "-").replace("\\xad", "-").replace("\\xa", "-").isalpha()]
lista
```

Looking for final output like this:

```
['ISBN-124123-A-112','ISBN-124312412412-D-2352342','AGEWE21-13-C-93872-0']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the construction element:

```
[i for i in lista if ...
```

You check the `isalpha` suitability of the string, but what you keep for your list is the *original* value of `i` !

Instead, you want to keep the altered value of `i`; just do any existing replacements, and forget the `isalpha` check entirely.

```
[i.replace("\{", "-").replace("\xad", "-").replace("\xa", "-") for i in lista]
```

Note that, if there are no occurrences of the special chars in the string, you simply get the original in your final list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single backslash to represent the literal string and you won't need to check if it is alpha cause it will always be false in your case.

```
lista = ['ISBN{124123{A{112','ISBN{124312412412{D{2352342','AGEWE21\xad13\xadC\xad93872\xa0']
[i.replace("{", "-").replace("\xad", "-").replace("\xa0", "-") for i in lista]

>>['ISBN-124123-A-112', 'ISBN-124312412412-D-2352342', 'AGEWE21-13-C-93872-']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lista = ['ISBN{124123{A{112', 'ISBN{124312412412{D{2352342', 
'AGEWE21\xad13\xadC\xad93872\xa0']
print([i.replace("{", "-").replace("\xad", "-").replace("\xa0", "") for i in lista])
```

It will print

```
['ISBN-124123-A-112', 'ISBN-124312412412-D-2352342', 'AGEWE21-13-C-93872']
```